# Consolidate Jenkins Email Notifications

Tags: jenkins

I have a Jenkins project consisting of 3 simple free-style jobs, each with their own build slave.  Each job is tied to a separate platform: linux, mac, or windows.  When a developer commits their code, Jenkins soon after polls the repo, builds the project on each of the build slaves, and each of those projects sends an email to the developer describing whether or not the build failed or succeeded.  **Problem:** Three separate emails per scm change really spams developers' inboxes, especially those belonging to people who like to commit small changes frequently.  They are therefore likely to ignore the emails entirely.

**Question:** Is there a way (via plug-in or project restructuring) to consolidate the three success/failure emails into one email?  I have looked into the *Email-ext* plugin, the *MultiJob* plugin and the *Build a multi-configuration project*  option and can't seem to find a way to change the project structure so that only one email is sent to a developer describing which jobs failed or succeeded.  I suspect you have to combine the jobs into a single MultiJob project and check results from building on each platform before sending, but I don't know.  There's a lot about Jenkins I haven't figured out yet.

Any advice you guys can give me would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The "Editable Email Notification" publisher (from email-ext) has a setting to decide how it deals with matrix (multi-configration) projects.

You can configure the "Trigger for matrix projects" to "Trigger only the parent job", which should achieve what you want.

Likewise you can also configure it to "Trigger for each configuration" to get the result you have now, or "Trigger for parent and each configuration" for both.

Comment: Thank you for your response!  I'll give it a shot and get back to you.

Comment: Can you please share the entire configuration of multiconfiguration job as well as normal jobs, screenshots would be helpful, because we are not able to achieve this. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

if you have 'n' freestyle jobs and you have to get one single email notification then go for Multijob plugin of jenkins.This is one of the approach.
Here you can run your jobs sequential or parallel. To consolidate the result to one email you need additional plugins like Copy Artifact , Groovy .

Below I am giving an example where I need to get the result of 2 freestyle jobs 'Job A' and 'Job B' in 1 single email

(Pre requisite :- Multijob, Artifact , Groovy plugins are installed in jenkins 
 The node in which you run the Jobs should have atleast 2 executors )
Steps to follow.

1. Create a multijob project (named it as 'Master')
2. In Add Build Step ----> MultiJob Phase 
   a. 'In phase 1' I added 'Job A' and in 'phase 2' added 'Job B' (Since I wanted my jobs to run sequential)
   b. If you want to execute your jobs parallel add 'Job A' and 'Job B' in 'phase 1'
3. 'Job A' and 'Job B' should check Permission to Copy Artifact and add Projects to allow copy artifacts as 'Master' (This would give the permission for the 'Master' to iterate through the subjob results)
4. Now for the 'Master' you need to add Groovy Script in Groovy post build (Add post-build action ---> Groovy Postbuild)

Below given is the groovy script I used to iterate through my subjobs result and then get the pass pertcentage to decide whether I need to set the status of the master as success or failed.Here  my jobs results are nunit result.

```
        import hudson.model.*
        import com.tikal.jenkins.plugins.multijob.*


        void log(msg) {
        manager.listener.logger.println(msg)
        }

        def boolean findpercent(int pass,int total) 
        {
        log 'Entered the function find percent' 
        def float percent = 0.0
        log percent
        percent = (pass/total) * 100
        log percent
        if(percent >= 90.0)
        {
            return true
        }else
        {
            return false
        }
        }

        threshold = Result.SUCCESS

        void aggregate_results() {
        def failed = false
        def  int totalTestCases = 0
        def  int  failedTestCases = 0
        def  int  passedTestcases = 0
        def  int skipTestcases = 0
        mainJob = manager.build.getProject().getName()
        job = hudson.model.Hudson.instance.getItem(mainJob)


        log '-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------'
        log 'Aggregated status report'
        log '-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------'

        log mainJob
        log job
        log manager.build.getNumber()
        log manager.build.getResult()

        job.getLastBuild().getSubBuilds().each { subBuild->
        subJob = subBuild.getJobName() 
        subJobNumber = subBuild.getBuildNumber()
        job1 = hudson.model.Hudson.instance.getItem(subBuild.getJobName())
        build = job1.getBuildByNumber(subJobNumber)
        log build
        log job1.getLastCompletedBuild().getResult()
        log job1.getLastCompletedBuild().getTestResultAction()
        log build.getResult()
        log subJobNumber 
        log subJob 
        log job1 
        log subBuild
        log build.getAllActions()
        log '-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------'
        log 'build.getTestResultAction()'
        log '-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------'
        log build.getTestResultAction()
        testResult = build.getTestResultAction()
        log testResult
        if (testResult != null) {
                total = testResult.getTotalCount()
                log total
                log totalTestCases
                totalTestCases += total
        log  totalTestCases 
                             failures = testResult.getFailCount()   
        log  failures 
        log failedTestCases  
                failedTestCases  +=    failures
        log failedTestCases  
                            skip = testResult.getSkipCount()
        log skip 
        log skipTestcases 
                skipTestcases +=  skip
                pass = total - (failures  + skip )
                log pass 
        passedTestcases += pass
        log pass 
        log passedTestcases 
                }
        }
        log 'Total testcases run'
        log totalTestCases 
        log 'Total failedTestCases'
        log failedTestCases 
        log 'Total skipTestcases'
        log skipTestcases 
        log 'Total passedTestcases'
        log passedTestcases
        log 'End Result'
        if(findpercent(passedTestcases,totalTestCases)) {
                   log 'success'
            manager.build.setResult(hudson.model.Result.SUCCESS)
        }else
           {
                    log 'failure'
            manager.build.setResult(hudson.model.Result.FAILURE)
        } 

         log 'time taken'
         log manager.build.getTimestampString()
         log 'Time End'

        }

        try 
        {
        aggregate_results()
        } 
        catch(Exception e) {
        log('ERROR: ${e.message}')
        log('ERROR: Failed Status report aggregation')

        }
```

5. Now in editable email notification I used the BUILD_LOG_EXCERPT to get the desired values. For example
   ${BUILD_LOG_EXCERPT, start = "Total passedTestcases", end="End Result"}
   This will return the value of the variable passedTestcases since it is present in between the log Total passedTestcases and End Result

   Note :- The slave node on which you run the jobs should have atleast 2 executors . Because here master will be running until all your subjobs run. So If its run sequentially you will need two executors. IF you need to run parallel you need n executors (n-1 subjobs and 1 master job).