# How to access environmental variables from a job by a different job in Jenkins

Tags: jenkins

here is my job setup

1. I have a master job (I am using [Multijob plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Multijob+Plugin) which is the driver job
2. I have 5 sub jobs which are called in the master job. each of these jobs will generate a nunit xml result file

What I am trying to attain : I want to send a mail at the end of the master job  with total number of passed and failed for each jobs. Any pointer on how to attain this.

I am using Email ext plugin to send out mails

*Expected Result Mail :*

**Job Status**

**Job 1** 
Total Tests : xxx  Passed : xxx  Failed : xxx

**Job 2** 
Total Tests : xxx  Passed : xxx  Failed : xxx

**Job 3**
Total Tests : xxx  Passed : xxx  Failed : xxx

**Job 4**
Total Tests : xxx  Passed : xxx  Failed : xxx

**Job 5**
Total Tests : xxx  Passed : xxx  Failed : xxx

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case apart from multi job plugin you need to use Copy Artifact Plugin https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Copy+Artifact+Plugin  and the groovy plugin https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Groovy+plugin  to loop inside the sub jobs and then get the result as you expected.

Hopefully the below answer helps you.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/35692855/5980759